# Display Tables on Tabs

Tags: r, tabs, shiny, dt

I have two tables containing different sets of data.  I want the tables to be displayed on separate tabs. My code works perfectly when I display just one table, but whenever I try to display both the tables values are no longer displayed, just the various titles.  Any help is much appreciated.  Below is my code.  I use the Lahman database and DT package.

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)


# Define a server for the Shiny app
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

 # Filter data based on selections
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
data <- Pitching
if (input$yearID != "All") {
  data <- data[data$yearID == input$yearID,]
}
if (input$lgID != "All") {
  data <- data[data$lgID == input$lgID,]
}
if (input$teamID != "All") {
  data <- data[data$teamID == input$teamID,]
}
data
}))

output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
data <- Batting
if (input$yearID != "All") {
  data <- data[data$yearID == input$yearID,]
}
if (input$lgID != "All") {
  data <- data[data$lgID == input$lgID,]
}
if (input$teamID != "All") {
  data <- data[data$teamID == input$teamID,]
}
data
}))


})
```

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

# Load the ggplot2 package which provides
# the 'mpg' dataset.
library(ggplot2)

# Define the overall UI
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Pitching"),

   # Create a new Row in the UI for selectInputs
   fluidRow(
    column(4,
         selectInput("yearID",
                     "Year:",
                     c("All",
                       unique(as.integer(Pitching$yearID))))
  ),
  column(4,
         selectInput("lgID",
                     "League:",
                     c("All",
                       unique(as.character(Pitching$lgID))))
  ),
  column(4,
         selectInput("teamID",
                     "Team:",
                     c("All",
                       unique(as.character(Pitching$teamID)))))
),

# Create a new row for the table.
fluidRow(
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")

),

fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Batting"),

  # Create a new Row in the UI for selectInputs
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           selectInput("yearID",
                       "Year:",
                       c("All",
                         unique(as.integer(Batting$yearID))))
    ),
    column(4,
           selectInput("lgID",
                       "League:",
                       c("All",
                         unique(as.character(Batting$lgID))))
    ),
    column(4,
           selectInput("teamID",
                       "Team:",
                       c("All",
                         unique(as.character(Batting$teamID)))))
  ),

  # Create a new row for the table.
  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("table2")

  ),

  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
    tabPanel("Pitching",tableOutput("table")),
    tabPanel("Batting", tableOutput("table2"))
  )
)
 )
  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are calling the tables twice (one in DT::dataTableOutput(), and again in tableOutput()). The table names (table and table2) are given IDs, which in valid HTML syntax can only be called once. You are calling them twice, which might be the reason why your tables are not showing up. Why do you need to call them twice?

Answer (score 0):

As Bogdan mentions you are attempting to render your tables twice in the `UI`. This appears to be your main issue.

You are most the way there, however your double call to render the table twice makes me think you're wanting the `pitching` to be on one tab and the `batting` to be on another.

See the updated `ui.R` file below:

```
library(shiny)

# Load the ggplot2 package which provides
# the 'mpg' dataset.
library(ggplot2)


# Define the overall UI
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                    tabPanel("Pitching",
    titlePanel("Pitching"),

    # Create a new Row in the UI for selectInputs
    fluidRow(
      column(4,selectInput("yearID","Year:",
                         c("All", unique(as.integer(Pitching$yearID))))
      ),
      column(4,selectInput("lgID","League:",
                         c("All",unique(as.character(Pitching$lgID))))
      ),
      column(4,selectInput("teamID","Team:",
                         c("All",unique(as.character(Pitching$teamID)))))
    ),

    # Create a new row for the table.
    fluidRow(
      DT::dataTableOutput("table")

    )),
    tabPanel("Batting",
      titlePanel("Batting"),

      # Create a new Row in the UI for selectInputs
      fluidRow(
        column(4,selectInput("yearID","Year:",
                           c("All",unique(as.integer(Batting$yearID))))
        ),
        column(4,selectInput("lgID","League:",
                           c("All",unique(as.character(Batting$lgID))))
        ),
        column(4,selectInput("teamID","Team:",
                           c("All",unique(as.character(Batting$teamID)))))
      ),

      # Create a new row for the table.
      fluidRow(
        DT::dataTableOutput("table2")
      )
      )
    )
  )))
```